# Проблема с базой данных

Tags: mysql

> `Could not connect: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Проверял настройки, пароль, юзер, хост подключения к базе - все верно, подскажите из-за чего может выскакивать такая ошибка?

Comment: А сервер то вообще запущен?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо)) Проблема решена) Вся загвоздка была в том что я первый раз переносил сайт с virtuemart, обычно я без него делал сайты, и в нем есть еще свои файлы, где просто нужно было правильно прописать хост базы данных)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего mysql.sock находится не в /tmp/,а где нибудь в другом месте, например в /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock - уточните в техподдержке
UPD:Кажется я случайно наткнулся на ваш предыдущий пост)))Если речь идёт о хостинге попробуйте отредактировать файл(могу ошибаться по поводу имени файла,сейчас нет возможности посмотреть) по-моему /includes/database.mysqli.php